# how to use image in ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

This is what I've done. First, I created a struct called Specialty with 3 lets:

```
let type:String
let color:Color
let image:Image
```

Then, in other struct, I wrote:

```
let specialtyList = [
        Specialty(type: "any_name", color: Color.any_color, image: Image("any_image") )]
```

In the body of the same struct that I wrote 'let spacialtyList', I have:

```
ForEach(specialtyList, id: \.type) { specialtyList in
    NavigationLink (destination: Any()) {
        HStack {
            Text(specialtyList.type)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            // Image(specialtyList.image)
            //    .renderingMode(.original)
            //  .resizable()
            //  .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 350, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .background(specialtyList.color)
    .cornerRadius(45)
}
```

The problem is that Image(specialtyList.image) don't work, I receive the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'String'"

I've tried to change 'specialtyList in' to 'Specialty in' but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to include image into image, just use property directly

```
ForEach(specialtyList, id: \.type) { specialty in
    NavigationLink (destination: Any()) {
        HStack {
            Text(specialty.type)

            specialty.image   // << it is already image
             // .. other code
        }
```